# Retrofit2 response is succesfull in the response.body the expected List of objects is null

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, retrofit2, kotlin-coroutines

First of all, I would like to say I am a novice in Android and Kotlin, so please, be patient. Once this has been said, I have found some posts related to a null retrofit response and that this response can be caused by a wrong data class, usually a different name of the variable than the one in the real JSON (frequently, this issue can be fixed using the @SerializedName annotation).

I am using other enpoints to my server and a response is always properly obtained by the Android application (simple responses with a JSON with only an id field for example). All the endpoints have been validated using Postman and a friend of mine use the same API for his iOS app, and it works well for him.

How retrofit is instantiated:

**requestMaker.kt**

```
interface ApiService {
    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @POST("getUserToken/")
    suspend fun getUserToken(@Body userData: getUserTokenRequestData): Response<getUserTokenResponse>

    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @POST("registerNewUserWithTables/")
    suspend fun signupNewUser(@Body userData: singupUserTokenRequestData): Response<singupUserTokenResponse>

    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @POST("getProductsByUserId/")
    suspend fun getUserProductsById(@Body userData: getUserProductsByIdRequestData): Response<getUserProductsByIdResponse>
}

class RequestsMaker {

    // Receive the context of the activity to pr
    lateinit var data: String


    object ApiClient {
        private const val BASE_URL: String = "http://myserver.com/"

        private val gson : Gson by lazy {
            GsonBuilder().setLenient().create()
        }

        private val httpClient : OkHttpClient by lazy {
            OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build()
        }

        private val retrofit : Retrofit by lazy {
            Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .client(httpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build()
        }

        val apiService : ApiService by lazy{
            retrofit.create(ApiService::class.java)
        }
    }

    fun getRequestService():ApiService{
        return ApiClient.apiService
    }
}
```

Data classes defined (I made it manually, but since this was failing I also used the "kotlin data class File from JSON" Android Studio plugin:

```
data class getUserProductsByIdRequestData(val id: Int)
data class getUserProductsByIdResponse(val products: productDataClass)

data class productDataClass(
    val locations: List<Location>
)

data class Location(
    val id: Int,
    val storageAreas: List<StorageArea>
)

data class StorageArea(
    val id: Int,
    val products: List<Product>
)

data class Product(
    val expirationDate: String,
    val id: Int,
    val name: String,
    val purchaseDate: String
)
```

The expected JSON response from the server is something like this (obtained by using Postman):

**POST request**

```
http://myserver.com/getProductsByUserId/

{
    "id": 1
}
```

**response**

```
{
    "locations": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "storageAreas": [
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "products": [
                        {
                            "id": 4,
                            "name": "Ipad Goloso",
                            "purchaseDate": "2021-06-01",
                            "expirationDate": "2021-05-25"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I use a coroutine to make the call and I use it like this:

```
private fun executeCall() {
    var retrofit = RequestsMaker().getRequestService()

    var request = getUserProductsByIdRequestData(id = 2)

    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
        try {
            var response = retrofit.getUserProductsById(request)

            if (response.isSuccessful && response.body() != null) {
                val content = response.body()
                if (content != null) {
                    Log.v("It worked message RESULT: ", content.toString())
                }
            }
            else {

                Log.w("Something went wrong with the request","lol")
                //Toast.makeText(context, "Something went wrong with the request", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            // This is the point to indicate the server is not responding
            Log.e("ExceptionError message", e.message.toString())
            Log.e("ExceptionError cause", e.cause.toString())
            Log.e("ExceptionError localizedMessage", e.localizedMessage.toString())
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "ERROR in the connection to the server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
}
```

But the result is that the products retrieved are always null...
[image: Undesired_response]

Any idea will be more than welcome because I do not find any useful information about how I could solve this after some days.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your retrofit function returns a getUserProductsByIdResponse.  That class expects a val products in its constructor.  It's not getting that-  the top level of the response is an array named "location".  So the product field (the only field in the response) will be set to null, and the rest of the data dropped.

In other words, your response data structure isn't matching the data actually being returned.  You're result has an extra layer.  Probably because you wrote it for a separate request that returns multiple products, while this one returns a single product.

Comment: Ok... That is true. Changing from products to locations it worked... Now I am getting other kind of errors but thank you very much. I was doing it well for the other but not for this, being stack for a couple of days. So, again, thank you :)